# Is it possible to have complete cold storage in NXT?

Tags: armory, offline, passphrase, coldstorage, nxt

BTC [has capability](https://bitcoinarmory.com/about/using-our-wallet/) to create new account on offline computer and send some coins to and from that account without ever going online.

Sending coins to that account is trivial.
Sending from that account is done by generating transaction on offline computer, saving it on flash drive or CD, inserting that media into online computer and feeding transaction to the network.

That way I can keep large chunk of my coins on my offline computer without worrying about keyloggers. Even if they got there during installation they won't be able to send anything because it's offline. The only thing they can do is corrupt my data, which is solved by backing keys up on another flash drive or CD.

Does [such possibility](https://nextcoin.org/index.php?topic=1112.0) exist in [NXT](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=303898.0) ?

Unlike BTC, new NXT account [has to send at least one outgoing transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/24216/14400) to become fully initialized by the network, otherwise [collisions may spoil it](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=366105.0). Sending money to that account [is not sufficient for initialization](https://nextcoin.org/index.php/topic,3973.msg37591.html#msg37591).

Can I generate and save and feed transaction in NXT like in BTC ?

If not then how am I supposed to initialize my offline NXT account without giving my password to online computer that may have keyloggers, viruses, NSA bots and whatever else runs on it ?

Is it possible to initialize NXT account with authorization token generated offline ?

Is it possible to send money or message or buy alias or participate in distributed exchange using authorization token or some other way generated offline ?

Does NXT have that feature in it's plans ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is the recommended way, but I did this by using the Send Nxt API call on an offline computer, storing the transaction bytes, and broadcasting the transaction from an online computer by using the Broadcast Transaction API call.

Comment: Great news, so it looks like it is already possible in NXT API, just UIs do not support it yet. Strange. This could be viewed as one significant disadvantage of NXT if people don't know about API.